What is behind these horizontal panel on the dry wall?
I have a task to paint the walls with high ceiling (~18 feet). At mid-height, there is horizontal panel that visually cuts the wall in half. My questions are:

What's likely to be behind these panels? Will there be seams between
separate dry walls, or is it likely to be just a plain dry wall?

Would you recommend removing these horizontal panels? Why and why
not?

Any functional purposes do these panels have other than visual?







Most often a way of hiding a poor joint. When put about 4ft off the floor it was decoration and protection from chair backs hitting the wall.

Most likely decoration/design statement and/or hiding a joint.  Besides adding some time to the paint prep, they are not hurting anything.  One idea is to paint them a different colour so they pop out of the wall.

"Poor joint" as in poor quality joints, with structural concerns? Or does it mean joints that need work to make it look smooth visually?

If the curved portion of wall surface is actually bending plywood, wiggle-wood, back-kerfed plywood, or some other bendable flat surface, the joints between the bendable surfaces probably wouldn't have had the beveled sides of standard drywall, and the horizontal strips would have been added to cover the raw joints between the bendable surfaces.
It is possible that a skilled drywall finisher could have taped and mudded these joints, but the horizontal strips were a less-skilled solution to covering the joints.

I have them both for curved high ceiling walls (on stairs) and flat walls (high ceiling). So they are most likely just for cosmetic and/or save time from the installers. I can simply remove them, put dry wall compound, sand, and paint over it so the walls look like a single unit?

Sure, most likely.

Well, you can try.  With a curved wall, there's no real guarantee that the butts of the drywall are flush enough to give you the seamless look you're going for—especially if the builder tried to hide the joint in the first place.
